# return results from a third method to another method

Tags: c#, oop

I have following problem:

- In method 1 I get a string list and pass it to method
- In method 2 I generate a 2d array based on the list and pass the list further to method 3
- In method 3 I convert the 2d array to a data table

Now I want to return the data table back to method 1, but I don't know how to do that. The picture shows my problem:

[image]

My code:

```
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            Document doc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
            View activeView = commandData.View;

            if(activeView is ViewSchedule)
            {
                GetDimensions(activeView as ViewSchedule);
            }

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public void GetDimensions(ViewSchedule schedule)
        {
            TableSectionData bodySelection = schedule.GetTableData().GetSectionData(SectionType.Body);
            int numberOfRows = bodySelection.NumberOfRows;
            int numberOfColumns = bodySelection.NumberOfColumns;
            string[,] values = new string[numberOfRows,numberOfColumns];
            FillArray(SectionType.Body, bodySelection, numberOfColumns, numberOfRows, values, schedule);
        }

        public void FillArray(SectionType secType, TableSectionData data, 
            int numberOfColumns, int numberOfRows, string[,] values, ViewSchedule schedule)
        {
            for (int r = data.FirstRowNumber; r < numberOfRows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = data.FirstColumnNumber; c < numberOfColumns; c++)
                {
                    values[r, c] = schedule.GetCellText(secType, r, c);
                }
            }

        }
```

Now I want to return the filled array to `Execute`.

Comment: Please post some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Method 3 returns to method 2, then method 2 returns to method 1. Or pass a reference type as a parameter and update that. Don't ask me to explain that, look it up yourself

Comment: Make functions 2 and 3 return type `string[,]` then return then result from each one. Might not be the best way overall, but easiest to explain for your code

Comment: Perhaps you need to refactor your code completely, i.e. encapsulate function 2&3 in a class(Scheduler) an then get the ScheduleList(return of FilledArray)-Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to pass it this way directly. There are three options:

- make method 2 take the result and pass it back:

  ```
  int Method2()
  {
      var method3Result = Method3();
      return method3Result;
  }

  void Method1()
  {
      var result = Method2(); //indirectly gets from Method3
  }
  ```
- provide a shared state:

  ```
  public class Method3Result { public int Value { get; set; } }

  public class X
  {
      private Method3Result method3Result = new Method3Result();

      public void Method1()
      {
          Method2();

          //process result from method3Result
      }

      public void Method2()
      {
          Method3();
      }

      public void Method3()
      {
          method3Result.Value = 3;
      }
  }
  ```
- provide a callback:

  ```
     public void Method1()
     {
          int method3Result;    
          Method2(value => method3Result = value);
      }

      public void Method2(Action<int> callback)
      {
          Method3(callback);
      }

      public void Method3(Action<int> callback)
      {
          callback(3);
      }
  }
  ```

In your case option 1 seems straightforward:

```
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
{
    Document doc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
    View activeView = commandData.View;

    string[,] values = null;
    if (activeView is ViewSchedule)
    {
        values = GetDimensions(activeView as ViewSchedule);
    }

    return Result.Succeeded;
}

public string[,] GetDimensions(ViewSchedule schedule)
{
    //...
    return values;
}
```

Also, it seems that it would be clearer to change `FillArray` to something like `CreateArray` and make it also return the array:

```
public void FillArray(SectionType secType, TableSectionData data, int numberOfColumns, int numberOfRows, string[,] values, ViewSchedule schedule)
{
    string[,] values = new string[numberOfRows,numberOfColumns];
    for (int r = data.FirstRowNumber; r < numberOfRows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = data.FirstColumnNumber; c < numberOfColumns; c++)
            {
                values[r, c] = schedule.GetCellText(secType, r, c);
            }
        }

return values;
}
```

so it's easier to use.

Comment: @musefan You should avoid void claims in comments and write an answer that indeed proves me wrong instead. The fact what the word makes people want is not really interesting in this topic.

Comment: Your first example already proves you can do what the OP has asked for... and the OP didn't use the word "directly", you made that up...

Comment: I didn't say that it's impossible what the OP asks for. I say it's impossible to do it directly. I didn't made up this word - I'm just informing the OP that "directly" is impossible, and provide ways to do it indirectly, hoping that these options satisfy them. You seem to read something from my answer that isn't really there.

Comment: If nobody asked for it, then why bother mentioning it at all... also, depends what your definition of "directly" is... I would say that it is possible, by my definition

Comment: @musefan The OP asked about ways to return values. Evaluating all possibilities seems a good approach to write a comprehensive answer that covers all possibilities, even if for some cases it boils down to "impossible". You're nitpicking and I'm really not sure what's your goal. Either propose some constructive improvement - I'll gladly consider it or, as I've proposed before, write your own answer using your definitions, ideas and whatever you think is better. Cheers!